# Obtener Información del Hardware con WMI (Windows Management Instrumentation)

Tags: c#

Encontré este código, pero solo devuelve los nombres. No he podido hacer que muestre los valores.

Debe a mostrar información de los siguientes objetos:

> Win32_Processor
> Win32_BaseBoard
> Win32_BIOS(BIOS)
> Win32_VideoController
> Win32_SoundDevice
> Win32_DiskDrive
> Win32_DiskPartition
> Win32_CacheMemory
> Win32_PhysicalMemory
> Win32_Process
> Win32_NetworkAdapter

```
using System.Management;

private void MuestraInformacion(string clave)
{
  ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from " + clave);
  listView1.Items.Clear();
  ListViewGroup lstvg;
  try
  {
    foreach (ManagementObject objeto in searcher.Get())
    {
      lstvg = listView1.Groups.Add(objeto["Name"].ToString(), objeto["Name"].ToString());
      if (objeto.Properties.Count <= 0)
      {
        MessageBox.Show("La Información No Está Disponible", "No Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        return;
      }

      foreach (PropertyData PropiedadObjeto in objeto.Properties)
      {
        ListViewItem listViewItem1 = new ListViewItem(lstvg);
        listViewItem1.Text = PropiedadObjeto.Name;
        if (PropiedadObjeto.Value != null && PropiedadObjeto.Value.ToString() != "")
        {
         
 listViewItem1.SubItems.Add(PropiedadObjeto.Value.ToString());
           listView1.Items.Add(listViewItem1);
        }
        else
        {
// Informacion nula
        }
      }
    }
  }
    
  catch (Exception exp)
  {
    MessageBox.Show("No se pueden obtener datos \n" + exp.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
  }
}
```

Uso:

```
//Procesador
MuestraInformacion("Win32_Processor");
//                   \_____________________________ String
```

Comment: Y el problema cuál es?

Comment: No me mostraba los valores. pero ya encontre el problema...

Answer (score 0):

Solo lo modifique un poco y corregí las propiedades del ListView

// Código

```
            private void SystemInformationWmi(string Key, ref ListView listView1, bool DontInsertNull)
    {
        listView1.Items.Clear();
        ListViewGroup GroupList;

        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from " + Key);

        try
        {
            foreach (ManagementObject share in searcher.Get())
            {

                try
                {
                    GroupList = listView1.Groups.Add(share.ToString(), share.ToString());
                    GroupList = listView1.Groups.Add(share["Name"].ToString(), share["Name"].ToString());
                }
                catch
                {
                    GroupList = listView1.Groups.Add(share.ToString(), share.ToString());
                }

                if (share.Properties.Count <= 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No se ha encontrado informacion disponible", "Sin informacion", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    return;
                }

                foreach (PropertyData PropData in share.Properties)
                {

                    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(GroupList);
                    if (listView1.Items.Count % 2 != 0)
                        item.BackColor = Color.White;
                    else
                        item.BackColor = Color.GhostWhite;

                    item.Text = PropData.Name;

                    if (PropData.Value != null && PropData.Value.ToString() != "")
                    {
                        switch (PropData.Value.GetType().ToString())
                        {
                            case "System.String[]":
                                string[] str = (string[])PropData.Value;

                                string str2 = "";
                                foreach (string st in str)
                                    str2 += st + " ";

                                item.SubItems.Add(str2);

                                break;
                            case "System.UInt16[]":
                                ushort[] shortData = (ushort[])PropData.Value;


                                string tstr2 = "";
                                foreach (ushort st in shortData)
                                    tstr2 += st.ToString() + " ";

                                item.SubItems.Add(tstr2);

                                break;

                            default:
                                item.SubItems.Add(PropData.Value.ToString());
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (!DontInsertNull)
                            item.SubItems.Add("Informacion no disponible");
                        else
                            continue;
                    }
                    listView1.Items.Add(item);
                }
            }
        }


        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ocurrio un error al intentar acceder a la información \n" + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }


    }

    private void RemoveNullValue(ref ListView listView1)
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
            if (item.SubItems[1].Text == "Sin Informacion")
                item.Remove();
    }
```

// Perdon por el desorden y la ortografia :)

Answer (score 0):

Si lo usan con boton asi seria el uso:
//Codigo:

```
    bontonxx_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)        {        
    //Procesador        
    string ListViewWmi = "Win32_Processor";        
    SystemInformationWmi(ListViewWmi.ToString(), ref 
    listView1, true);        
    }
```

Simple :)